# What is the meaning of the phrase "get out of a jar of pickles?"

Tags: idioms

I came across this word in my workbook. The sentence in which this phrase was used is:

What can I do to get out of this jar of pickles?

Well, there is a literal translation here but I am wondering if there a figurative explanation to this particular expression.

Thanks all!

[A jar of pickles... Hmm](https://www.google.co.kr/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Faz616578.vo.msecnd.net%2Ffiles%2Fresponsive%2Fembedded%2Fany%2Fdesktop%2F2017%2F03%2F29%2F636263494223641716-2096438085_jar%2520of%2520pickles.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.theodysseyonline.com%2Fdeal-pickle-jars&docid=sV-E9Wn_0rCP5M&tbnid=D-WXv5D3VhlftM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwiI3cTqjO_UAhWBQJQKHakYA84QMwgxKAQwBA..i&w=200&h=300&client=ms-android-lgu-kr&bih=604&biw=412&q=jar%20of%20pickles&ved=0ahUKEwiI3cTqjO_UAhWBQJQKHakYA84QMwgxKAQwBA&iact=mrc&uact=8)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***[A jar of pickles](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Jar%20of%20Pickles):***

> - Any situation that you normally would not over-react to, but since you're already under a lot of stress from other situations, you blow it out of proportion.

(UD)

So, "get out of this jar of pickles" means "get out of/solve a difficult situation" in which you are involved.

As suggested in the following extract the expression is used figuratively to refers to a "very difficult situation" and it may have  originated from the more common idiomatic expression "in a pickle":

> ***Let's start with "[in a (pretty) pickle](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+a+pickle)"*** because it's easier to explain. ***This is a well-known, well-used English idiom with the figurative meaning of "experiencing a problem" or "in a mess" or "in trouble":***
>
> - *Mary has gotten into a pickle. She has booked two different places on the same date for the same conference and the bookings can't be cancelled.*
>
> ***It is often used with a word describing the type of difficulty:***
>
> - *You're going to put yourself in a legal pickle if you publish that without permission.*
>
> ***The phrase "[jar of pickles](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-people-say-%E2%80%9Cjar-of-pickles%E2%80%9D-Is-the-phrase-related-to-%E2%80%9Cin-a-pickle%E2%80%9D)" seemed to have evolved from the above idiom.***  (How, I don't know.) So it means any situation (the 'jar,' so to speak) that you wouldn't normally overreact to, but because you're somehow already under a lot of stress from something else (the 'pickles'), you overreact (blow it out of proportion):

(Quora)

The figurative meaning of ***[pickle](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pickle)*** has an old origin:

> Originally a sauce served with meat or fowl; meaning "cucumber preserved in pickle" first recorded 1707, via use of the word for the salty liquid in which meat, etc. was preserved (c. 1500). ***Figurative sense of "sorry plight" first recorded 1560s, from the time when the word still meant a sauce served on meat about to be eaten.***

(Etymonline)

Origin of ***[in a pickle](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/in-a-pickle.html)*** :

> The earliest pickles were spicy sauces made to accompany meat dishes. Later, in the 16th century, the name pickle was also given to a mixture of spiced, salted vinegar that was used as a preservative. The word comes from the Dutch or Low German pekel, with the meaning of 'something piquant'. Later still, in the 17th century, the vegetables that were preserved, for example cucumbers and gherkins, also came to be called pickles.
>
> ***The 'in trouble' meaning of 'in a pickle' was an allusion to being as disoriented and mixed up as the stewed vegetables that made up pickles.***  This was partway to being a literal allusion, as fanciful stories of the day related to hapless people who found themselves on the menu. The earliest known use of pickle in English contains such an citation.
>
> ***The figurative version of the phrase***, meaning simply 'in a fix' or, in the almost identical 19th century phrase 'in a stew', ***arrives during the next century. Thomas Tusser's Five Hundreth Pointes of Good Husbandrie, 1573, contains this useful advice:***
>
> - *Reape barlie with sickle, that lies in ill pickle.*

(The Phrase Finder)